# Where to find source code change of Redhat Product

Tags: redhat, openstack

Regarding to the GPLv3, Redhat product need to inform what they changes from the open source. I want to find that changes. Do you know where they put this information ?

Answer (score 2):

You can log in to your Red Hat account and download the SRPM (source code RPM) package for any package for which you have a valid subscription. These contain the original source code for the software and all of the patches Red Hat applied to it.

Click on **[Downloads](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/)**, then choose the product you want to obtain source code for, then click **Packages** to download the source for a single package, or **Source** to obtain the Source DVD corresponding to the installation DVD.

For example, here I will obtain the source package for `bash` in RHEL 7.8.

1. Click on **Downloads**, and the product list appears.

   [image: RHEL Downloads]
2. Click on **Versions 7 and below**, and then select version 7.8 in the drop-down.

   [image: RHEL 7.8 Downloads]
3. Click on **Packages**, and then type `bash` into the search box.

   [image: RHEL package search for bash]
4. Click on **bash**, then scroll down to find the Source Package, and click **Download Now**.

   [image: RHEL packages for bash]

People without an active subscription have a couple of options:

1. You can look around [Red Hat's FTP server](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub) (or via [https](https://ftp.redhat.com/pub)) to locate an SRPM of interest, though the directory structure is not well documented and therefore it may be hard to find a specific package.
2. Red Hat also publishes its source to [git.centos.org](https://git.centos.org/) where people can download package source changes and RPM specs via git.

Answer (score 1):

All RPM packages are built from SRPM , source code packages which you can download.

Those SRPM packages typically contain among others a pristine source code release downloaded from an upstream open source project as well as all (code) changes / additions made by the package maintainer (Red Hat).